# Telephony API alternative for Linux?

Tags: linux, windows, unix-sockets, telephony

Is there is any Telephony API for Linux like we have "Tapi.h" for Windows?

Comment: A very similar questions already exists on Stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7267903/2519977

Answer (score 2):

Not sure whether it's what you're looking for but there is [Asterisk](http://www.asterisk.org/), an open-source software implementation of a telephone PBX. It allows calls and connection to telephone services such as PSTN and VoIP.